# xslt test/match current node with another node

Tags: xml, xslt

Hello I am trying to test if my current node matches another node. This is my xml:

```
<top-level>
<ep-bulletin>
    <SDOBI>
        <B200>
            <B210>R1</B210>
        </B200>
        <B400>
            <B472>
                <B475>
                    <date>20030221</date>
                    <ctry>GB</ctry>
                    <date>20030222</date>
                    <ctry>LU</ctry>
                </B475>
            </B472>
        </B400>
        <B800>
            <B840>
                <ctry>DE</ctry>
                <ctry>FR</ctry>
                <ctry>GB</ctry>
                <ctry>IT</ctry>
                <ctry>LU</ctry>
                <ctry>SE</ctry>
            </B840>
        </B800>
    </SDOBI>
</ep-bulletin>
<ep-bulletin>
    <SDOBI>
        <B200>
            <B210>R2</B210>
        </B200>
        <B400>
            <B472>
                <B475>
                    <date>20040609</date>
                    <ctry>AT</ctry>
                    <date>20110630</date>
                    <ctry>BE</ctry>
                    <date>20110630</date>
                    <ctry>CH</ctry>
                    <date>20120103</date>
                    <ctry>DE</ctry>
                    <date>20110630</date>
                    <ctry>DK</ctry>
                    <date>20110630</date>
                    <ctry>FR</ctry>
                    <date>20110612</date>
                    <ctry>GB</ctry>
                    <date>20110612</date>
                    <ctry>IT</ctry>
                    <date>20110630</date>
                    <ctry>LI</ctry>
                    <date>20120101</date>
                    <ctry>NL</ctry>
                    <date>20110613</date>
                    <ctry>SE</ctry>
                </B475> 
            </B472>
        </B400>
        <B800>
            <B840>                          

                <ctry>AT</ctry>
                <ctry>BE</ctry>
                <ctry>CH</ctry>
                <ctry>DE</ctry>
                <ctry>DK</ctry>
                <ctry>ES</ctry>
                <ctry>FR</ctry>
                <ctry>GB</ctry>
                <ctry>IT</ctry>
                <ctry>LI</ctry>
                <ctry>NL</ctry>
                <ctry>SE</ctry>
            </B840>
        </B800>
    </SDOBI>
</ep-bulletin>
</top-level>
```

I would like to be able to check whether B800/B840/ctry is contained in B400/B475/ctry. The output I would like to obtain is a table containing in the first column a record id, in the second column the my current node and in the third the node B475/date preceding the matched nodes (|~| is the text identifier and ; the separator).

```
|~|R1|~|;|~|DE|~|;|~||~|
|~|R1|~|;|~|FR|~|;|~||~|
|~|R1|~|;|~|GB|~|;|~|20030221|~|
|~|R1|~|;|~|IT|~|;|~||~|
|~|R1|~|;|~|LU|~|;|~|20030222|~|
|~|R1|~|;|~|SE|~|;|~||~|
|~|R2|~|;|~|AT|~|;|~|20040609|~|
|~|R2|~|;|~|BE|~|;|~|20110630|~|
|~|R2|~|;|~|CH|~|;|~|20110630|~|
|~|R2|~|;|~|DE|~|;|~|20120103|~|
|~|R2|~|;|~|DK|~|;|~|20110630|~|
|~|R2|~|;|~|ES|~|;|~||~|
|~|R2|~|;|~|FR|~|;|~|20110630|~|
|~|R2|~|;|~|GB|~|;|~|20110612|~|
|~|R2|~|;|~|IT|~|;|~|20110612|~|
|~|R2|~|;|~|LI|~|;|~|20110630|~|
|~|R2|~|;|~|NL|~|;|~|20120101|~|
|~|R2|~|;|~|SE|~|;|~|20110613|~|
```

This is the xslt code that I wrote, but I am not able to obtain the last column.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no"/>
<xsl:template match="/">

<xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text>

<xsl:for-each select="top-level/ep-bulletin/SDOBI/B800/B840/ctry">

<xsl:text>|~|</xsl:text>

<xsl:value-of select="../../../B200/B210"/>

<xsl:text>|~|;|~|</xsl:text>

<xsl:value-of select="."/>

<xsl:text>|~|;|~|</xsl:text>

<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test=".=child::B475">
<xsl:value-of select="../../../preceding::B475/ctry"/>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise >
<xsl:value-of select="">
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>

<xsl:text>|~|</xsl:text>
<xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text>

</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you think `.=child::B475` should achieve, but I think you can simplify things a fair bit, replacing the whole of

```
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test=".=child::B475">
<xsl:value-of select="../../../preceding::B475/ctry"/>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise >
<xsl:value-of select="">
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

with just

```
<xsl:value-of select="../../../B400/B472/B475
                      /ctry[. = current()]/preceding-sibling::date[1]" />
```

If there is a `ctry` under `B475` that matches the current one then this will print the `date` that comes immediately before it (if there happens to be more than one matching `ctry` then you'll get the `date` before the *first* one that matches).  If there is no such `ctry` it'll print nothing.  You don't need the `choose` because `value-of` will give you the empty string automatically if its `select` expression doesn't find any nodes (the `value-of` an empty node set is defined to be the empty string).